# Convert String ISO-8601 date to oracle's timestamp datatype

Tags: database, oracle, iso8601

I have a ISO-8601 date in VARCHAR2 type, how can i convert that String date to timestamp in oracle db?

Date Example: "2014-09-12T11:53:06+00:00"

Maybe is something like the following but i not sure what is the format.

```
SELECT to_timestamp_tz ('2014-09-12T11:53:06+00:00', ????) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The date format model elements are listed in the [Datetime Format Models documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212):

```
SELECT to_timestamp_tz ('2014-09-12T11:53:06+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
FROM DUAL

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-09-12T11:53:06+00:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12-SEP-14 11.53.06.000000000 +00:00
```

The fixed `T` can be included as a character literal:

> You can include these characters in a date format model:
>
> - Punctuation such as hyphens, slashes, commas, periods, and colons
> - Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks

`TZH` is tome zone hour, and `TZM` is time zone minutes. The rest are more common model elements.

Answer (score -1):

I had an app that was making queries against an OracleDB database (19c).
The app was sending timestamp parameters in ISO 8601 format and the table had a column that was an Oracle TIMESTAMP type (not an Oracle TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE type) that was just known to store timestamps that represented UTC time.

I thought the following query would work but it didn't seem to recognize the literals that were surrounded by double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM measurements
WHERE measID = '333'
AND measTime > to_timestamp('2020-11-19T05:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"');
-- Doesn't Work
-- ORA-01810: format code appears twice
-- 01810. 00000 -  "format code appears twice"
```

The following did work for me:

```
SELECT * FROM measurements
WHERE measID = '333'
AND measTime > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-11-19T05:00:00Z'));
-- Works
```

Sharing because formatting ISO 8601 to TIMESTAMP types wasn't immediately clear in Oracle documentation.
I found this solution here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/to_utc_timestamp_tz-function-18c

Comment: You had a typo ...YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"... should be ...YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh:mi:ss"Z"... Notice the mm -> mi for minutes.

Comment: Also, replace `hh` with `hh24` to get for instance 19 instead of 07 (pm).