# Oracle SQL query statement and conditions with timestamps and ISO dates

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, isodate

I need a query which will select records from Oracle database on the basis of the datetime condition. Example below:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE [modification_date] >= '2014-01-28T12:00:00Z';
```

As datetime I used ISO date and this is "Must be". In Oracle XE database a [modification_date] column has type "Timestamp with time zone".
And now is my question - How to convert ISO date in query to proper searching on database ?

I tried adding to_timestamp_tz to query statement.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE MODIFICATION_DATE >= to_timestamp_tz('2014-01-28T00:00:0Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

But get this error:

> SQL Error [1830] [22008]: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before
>   converting entire input string

Comment: `[modification_date]` is an invalid name for a column. Plus: `'2014-01-28T12:00:00Z'` is not a "ISO date". It's a string literal, you need to use `to_timestamp()` to create a proper timestamp value.

Comment: Probably a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26671557/266304); but is your Z fixed too?

Comment: Doesn't Oracle support `TIMESTAMP'2014-01-28T12:00:00Z'` literals?

Comment: @vanzen - yes, because of your Z at the end. If that is fixed include that in double quotes too, but you might want to replace it with UTC and use the TZR model, or include an `at time zone utc` clause?

Comment: Ok, i got it.

Query should look like:
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MODIFICATION_DATE >= to_timestamp_tz('2014-01-28T13:00:0Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"');`

Comment: @jarlh - [Not with the T and Z embedded, no](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062).

Comment: @Alex - unfortunately the date format is dictated from above. I have to keep this convention.

Comment: @jarlh, no timestamp literal must be `TIMESTAMP '2014-01-28 12:00:00 UTC'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26671665/266304), it's tempting to treat both the T and Z as character literals, and basically ignore them, using:

```
to_timestamp_tz('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
```

If you use `to_timestamp_tz()` without specifying a timezone then it defaults to your session time zone, as would `to_timestamp()`; so a time specified in Zulu/UTC loses that zone information:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';
select to_timestamp_tz('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
-------------------------------------------------------------------
28-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
```

Your 12:00 time is shown as 12:00 in New York, not 12:00 UTC.

A safer conversion, assuming your values are always supposed to represent UTC, is to specify the time zone explicitly with [the `from_tz()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions068.htm):

```
WHERE MODIFICATION_DATE >= from_tz(to_timestamp('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'), 'UTC')
```

This gets the UTC time properly:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';
select from_tz(to_timestamp('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'), 'UTC') from dual;

FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),'UTC')
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 UTC
```

Comment: You can also use `to_timestamp_TZ('2014-01-28T12:00:0Z'||'UTC',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"TZR')`

Comment: Use `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'` and it will match both `2017-01-10T00:00:00Z`, `2017-01-10T00:00:00+0000` and `2017-01-10T00:00:00+00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [to_timestamp_tz](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) function.

Assuming Z is for Zulu/UTC, you ca probably do a replace of Z with +00:00 and work with to_timestamp_tz function

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE modification_date >= to_timestamp_tz(replace('2014-01-28T12:00:00z','z','+00:00'),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:tzm')
```

Comment: You do not need to replace `z` with `+00:00`. Using the format mask `TZH:TZM` will match the `z` character and set the time zone to zulu time (`+00:00`). So you can just do `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( :your_isotime, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' )`.