# How to transform ISO DATE to Timestamp in Java or SQL?

Tags: java, oracle, mongodb, timestamp, isodate

I am using Mongo and Oracle 12c at the same time.

For MongoDB I am using `ISO DATE` (but like String) to persist date. Like this:

```
{
            "_id" : null,
            "fields" : {
                "Status" : "UnderInvestigation",
                "Assignee" : "",
                "CreationDate" : "2016-12-14T00:00:00Z", //ISO DATE
                "CaseId" : "8165021",
                "RunningMode" : "STS",
                "CloserDueDate" : ""
            },
            "domain" : {},
            "arrays" : {}
        }
```

I want use Timestamp format type in Oracle for a column with the same name, so the idea is transform that date to timestamp.

I don't know how to do that. I have the follow code but it doesn't work.

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_APPLICATION + " (CreationDate) VALUES (TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))" ;
PreparedStatement ps = getPreparedStatement();
((OraclePreparedStatement) ps).setString(1, getValueFromJson(JSON, 'fields.CreationDate'));
```

But I got:

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato

What's the problem?

Comment: [Like this in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28211019/266304); but the title says you want to do it in Java, so which do you really mean? Also what data type is the column, and do you intend to convert the UTC value to a local time? If it's a date and you don't want to adjust it, you could use the same format mask with `to_date()`, but that wouldn't be strictly correct.

Comment: how is the code set up in `getFieldFromJson` method ? are you using  Mongo java driver to handle the mapping ? You should try to store date as date type in mongo db too. So you dont have to convert and you can just read from MongoDB and save it to oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle solution:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         '2016-12-14T00:00:00Z',
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

So your code should be:

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_APPLICATION + " ("
                        + "CreationDate"
                        + ") VALUES ("
                        + "TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( ?, 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')"
                        + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

I SimpleDateFormat parse your field Date and getTime() you return millisTime exact.

```
//String base = "YYYY-MM-ddTkk:mm:ssZ";
//"date": "2016-11-22T16:59:01+01:00"

String timeform = "YYYY-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss-Z";
Date datec = new Date();

//si null ont crée une nouvelle date
if (!json.isNull("date"))
{
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(timeform, Locale.FRANCE);
    try {
        datec = format.parse(json.getString("date"));
    } catch (ParseException e){}
}
datec.getTime();
```

Comment: Incorrect. That formatting pattern does match the input string. Ignores the `T` in the middle of a standard ISO 8601 formatted string.

Comment: @GyGy19 I agree, the date change if el use this code :(

Comment: Yes from Location !

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

To do this in Java rather than SQL, use the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default. So, no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-12-14T00:00:00Z" );
```

If your JDBC driver supports JDBC 4.2 or later, you can pass/fetch java.time objects via the [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)/`ResultSet::getObject` methods.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , instant );
```

Or perhaps you need to specify the [`SQLType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLType.html).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , instant , JDBCType.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE );
```

If your JDBC driver does not specify the java.time types, fall back to using the old java.sql types. Call new methods added to the old classes for conversion.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( 1 , ts );
```

Your Question really is a duplicate of many others. Search Stack Overflow for these class names to get more examples and discussion.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).