# Converting XML date (ISO-8601) into timestamp in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Could you please help me in converting date time of format from "2015-02-23T16:26:41.485+05:30" to "23-FEB-15 16.26.41.000000000 AM" in Oracle.

I have an ISO-8601 date string in variable:

```
START_TIME='2015-02-23T16:26:41.485+05:30'
```

When I use

```
to_timestamp(START_TIME,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
```

I get:

```
Error report:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
ORA-06512: at line 55
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: I was tempted to close as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26671557/266304), but (a) you seem to be truncating the fractional seconds so why are you keeping it as a timestamp and more importantly (b) your target seems to be a timestamp without a time zone, so do you need to do any translation or are you assuming the value and your database are always in the same time zone (+05:30)? Is the time zone value always going to be fixed in your input data, so it will always be +05:30 and you can ignore it, or will it vary - even with summertime?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. we need to put it as timestamp as per our client requirement, my database always starts witha timezone of +5:30 so we dont want to include timezone. My main concern is am getting the date time from an external application through XML. Iam able to get the value into variable but am not able to declare variable in to_timestamp statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your string to a timestamp with time zone value, you need [the `to_timestamp_tz()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions214.htm):

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2015-02-23T16:26:41.485+05:30',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3tzh:tzm') as result
from dual;

RESULT                             
-----------------------------------
2015-02-23 16:26:41.485000 +05:30
```

This includes the TZH and TZM [datetime format model elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) to handle the time zone offset; those can't be used in `to_timestamp()` or `to_date()` as those data types don't understand time zones.

You seem to want to lose the fractional seconds part, and the time zone information; you can achieve both at once by casting to a timestamp (without timezone) with the fractional seconds precision set to zero:

```
select cast(to_timestamp_tz('2015-02-23T16:26:41.485+05:30',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3tzh:tzm') as timestamp(0)) as result
from dual;

RESULT                             
-----------------------------------
2015-02-23 16:26:41.000000
```

But losing the time zone seems dangerous, unless you are sure that the data you receive is always going to be in the same time zone as your database. If you might have different time zones in the data but for some reason don't want to retain that information, you can also convert to a specific time zone for storage, but it isn't clear whether you need or want that here. If you aren't keeping the time zone or the fractional seconds, you may be better off with a date anyway.

Dates and timestamps do not have any inherent format within the database. If you then want to see that converted back into a string in the format you specified, pass it back into a `to_char()` call with the formatting you want; but as your example has both a 24-hour-clock hour value and an (incorrect) AM/PM indicator that isn't clear either. Maybe you want:

```
select to_char(cast(to_timestamp_tz('2015-02-23T16:26:41.485+05:30',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3tzh:tzm') as timestamp(0)),
  'dd-MON-rr hh:mi:ss.ff9 am') as result
from dual;

RESULT                             
-----------------------------------
23-FEB-15 04:26:41.000000000 PM
```

To store the value from your `START_TIME` variable in a timestamp column the approach is exactly the same, just use that instead of the fixed value I've used above to demonstrate the conversion:

```
cast(to_timestamp_tz(START_TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3tzh:tzm')
  as timestamp(0))
```

Comment: Hi Alex, My approach is bit different. I have a variable START_TIME whose value is '2015-02-23T16:26:41.485+05:30' now I want to convert this to timezone format by using variable. so that I can store output into table. Am using stored procedure where I will get input as xml.

Comment: @user2582284 - so replace the fixed value I used to demo this in plain SQL with your `start_time` variable? Am I missing something? I've added the equivalent of what you had in the question...

Comment: it doesnt work. Iam running a proc as below DECLARE
 a number;
 
DECLARE
 a number;
 
BEGIN
SELECT max(audit_log_id) into a FROM inventory;

FOR cur_rec IN (
    select inve.audit_log_id, xt.*
    from Inventory inve,
         XMLTable('/ld:LoggingDetails'
                  PASSING inve.Inv
                  COLUMNS
    "START_TIME" VARCHAR2(500) path 'ld:TILStrtTm') xt
    where inve.audit_log_id = a )
loop
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(to_timestamp(cur_rec.START_TIME,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3'));
end loop;
END;

Comment: Am getting date format errors when I use the constant in above approach. Please help.

Comment: @user2582284 - I don't understand, that block is still using your original `to_timestamp()` call, not my modified one with `to_timestamp_tz()`.

Comment: still same errot :( .. loop
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(to_timestamp_tz(cur_rec.START_TIME,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3'));
end loop;
END;
Error report:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
ORA-06512: at line 55
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: you are correct sorry I overlooked at the zone part.... Thanks alot :) ... Sorry for troubling you....