# Format date in SQL for a specified format

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have recieved a particular date in the particular format
2015-06-13T21:49:13.395-07:00 which is inserted as varchar in database.

I want to convert this date into DATE format but am not getting the right formatter for the same

Comment: Have you used `to_date()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String ISO-8601 date to oracle's timestamp datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671557/convert-string-iso-8601-date-to-oracles-timestamp-datatype)

Answer (score 5):

Use `to_timestamp_tz()` function to convert your string to a value of timestamp with timezone data type:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2015-06-13T21:49:13.395-07:00'
                      , 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ffTZH:TZM') as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES                              
----------------------------------
13.06.15 21:49:13,395000000 -07:00
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas can i convert this to a particular format to a column? basically i used substrings to convert it to MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss.But is there a direct or an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(REPLACE('2015-06-13T21:49:13.395-07:00','T',' '),23) AS DATETIME)
```