# Oracle Date formatting 9999-06-15T00:00:00.000+0000 in 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle12c, to-timestamp

I have got a date coming from the webservice in 9999-06-15T00:00:00.000+0000 format.
How do i save this into the date column of a table in Oracle 12c DB.

I have tried

```
 select to_date('9999-06-15T00:00:00.000+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.fff+0000')
 from dual;
```

but i get an error "ORA-01821:date format not recognized"

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String ISO-8601 date to oracle's timestamp datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671557/convert-string-iso-8601-date-to-oracles-timestamp-datatype)

Comment: You can't use `to_date()` with fractional seconds or time zones (regions or offsets). If the those parts are always zeros you could ignore them; otherwise you need to convert it to a timestamp with timezone. You can then cast that to a date if you need to - or it will happen implicitly when you insert; but you'll lose the fractional seconds and time zone info.

Answer (score 1):

The literal's format comforms to `timestamp` data type instead of `date` data type. So, using `to_timestamp` conversion would suffice if it had a format without the trailing portion starting from plus sign as

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-06-15T00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS ts      
  FROM dual;
```

quoting letter `T` as `"T"`, and suffixing with `.FF3` instead of `fff` as in your original format mask. Having that trailing part we need a conversion `WITH TIME ZONE` (`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`) which has `TZH` (`Time Zone Hour`) and `TZM` (`Time Zone Minute`) portions after plus sign. So, use

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('9999-06-15T00:00:00.000+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM') AS ts
  FROM dual;
```

conforming to your data model.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e02a1493539985fd841d691b5f2691e5)</kbd>