# Oracle sql query to split data in between the dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle sql query which gives the average battery voltage for a day

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(BATTERYVOLTAGE),2)AVGVOLTAGE
FROM table
WHERE datattime>'01:00:00' and datattime<'24:00:00' and datadate='22/04/2021';
```

Now i wanted to view the average voltage for each day between the selected days by the user: FOR EXAMPLE

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(BATTERYVOLTAGE),2)AVGVOLTAGE
FROM table
WHERE datattime>'01:00:00' and datattime<'12:00:00' and datadate between '23/04/2021' and '27/04/2021';
```

This sql works but just gives me one avg value from 23 to 27. Is there anything I can do to split the average values of each days  between  24 and 27 .

In short i want the query to give me 5 different outputs of each day instead of one. Is there any possibility. Sorry if this is not possible, I'm a newbie to databases.

Why sql with only two dates?
I have a date picker in which the user selects 2 dates. So now the user wants to view the data from (23,24,25,26,27). The datepicker can only choose 2 dates!! So he/she will pick 23 to 27 and i pass it to the Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` using the `datadate`?  *(And using ISO8601 for date literals)*

```
  SELECT datadate, ROUND(AVG(BATTERYVOLTAGE),2)AVGVOLTAGE
    FROM table
   WHERE datattime>'01:00:00' and datattime<'12:00:00'
     AND datadate between '2021-04-23' and '2021-04-27'
GROUP BY datadate
```

[Convert String ISO-8601 date to oracle's timestamp datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671557/convert-string-iso-8601-date-to-oracles-timestamp-datatype)

Comment: @JCH Don't use strings for date dtat types; use a `DATE` literal then you are not reliant on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. The code should be `datadate between DATE '2021-04-23' and DATE '2021-04-27'`. Even better, would be to merge the `datadate` and `datatime` columns into a single `DATE` column (since the `DATE` data type has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components).